# How do I move my UIView bottom anchor right about my bottom navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a controller that will display UIView that displays a text field at the bottom, but I already have a navigation bar down there so whenever I run the simulator, the navigation bar covers it. How would I move that UIView right above my navigation bar? I was messing around with the anchors but I am still having trouble. I was messing around with the containerView.bottomAnchor.

```
import UIKit

class ChatLogController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Chat Log Controller"

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        setUpInputComponents()

    }

    func setUpInputComponents() {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(containerView)

        containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true



        let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
        sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(sendButton)
        sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        let inputTextField = UITextField()
        inputTextField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
        inputTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(inputTextField)

        inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        inputTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true


        let seperatorLineView = UIView()
        seperatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        seperatorLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(seperatorLineView)

        seperatorLineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        seperatorLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        seperatorLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        seperatorLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true


    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdyRV.jpg

Comment: how did you add the bottom navigation? can you add the bottom navigation constraints

Answer (score 0):

Set `tabBarController.tabBar.translucent` to `true` to make your tabbar opaque.

```
tabBarController.tabBar.opaque = true
tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = true
```